# Using A Delimiter to parse data into separate strings

Tags: c++, string, file-io, delimiter

I've done parsing before using a function similar to this:

```
  string url;
  string hash;
  string urlName;
  int bytes;    



  while (infile >> url >> hash >> bytes){
  {
```

But this only works because there is whitespace inside the txt file separating the different types of data so using url>> hash>> bytes works .

I want to do something similar to this but instead of having the different types of data parsed by using whitespace I want to use a delimiter. for example:

```
  Oklahoma City,OK,73124-2412


  while (infile >> cityname >> state >> postal){
  {
```

If I use the method above It will still parse based off the whitespace. Instead I want to parse this data by using the ',' and after every ',' the next section is part of a different string than the first and so on. My best idea for this would be by using a delimiter. But I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Looks like you want [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), which can accept any `char` as a delimiter

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would write it, assuming the tokens are seperated by commas only:

```
while (std::getline(infile, cityname, ',') &&
       std::getline(infile, state,    ',') &&
       std::getline(infile, postal,   ','))
```